# C++ Qt and WinExec - save CMD output to file in specific folder

Tags: c++, qt, file-io, directory

I use the following to save the BIOS serial number to a file in the same folder as the application:

```
WinExec("cmd.exe /c wmic bios get serialnumber > sn.txt", SW_HIDE);
```

My question is how can I save the file to a different folder?
Something like this:

```
WinExec("cmd.exe /c wmic bios get serialnumber > /some_folder/sn.txt", SW_HIDE);
```

I tried every combination of \ and / to specify a folder but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please note that **the `WinExec` function went obsolete *nearly 20 years ago*** with the introduction of 32-bit Windows 95. `WinExec` is a 16-bit function, supported for backwards compatibility only. As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687393.aspx) indicates, you should be using [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) instead. *Please* change your code before going any further!

Comment: If you are using Qt, you could use QProcess instead of WinAPI.

Comment: How can I accomplish the same functionality using CreateProcess or QProcess?

Comment: The most simple: `QProcess process;`
 `process.start("your command");`
See the spec: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you just need to specify a proper relative path:

```
WinExec("cmd.exe /c wmic bios get serialnumber > drive:\\<path_to_folder>\\some_folder\\sn.txt", SW_HIDE);
```

or in your case looks like you want to specify folder within your program's directory `.\<path>`:

```
WinExec("cmd.exe /c wmic bios get serialnumber > .\\some_folder\\sn.txt", SW_HIDE);
```

Make sure this folder exists before writing. If not, the system won't find the path specified.

Comment: You need to escape those backslashes.

Comment: thanks, I just wanted the relative path and didn't put the dot before backslashes...